# Loading bitmaps takes too long

Tags: android

So I'm making an app that displays captured images. I first save the snapped images in a static ArrayList of String (In the code below: methods.locationPath), and then converts these strings to bitmaps and save them in an ArrayList of Bitmap (In the code below: images).

```
for (String path : methods.locationPath) {
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
  images.add(bitmap);
}

gr = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
GridAdapter gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, values,images);
gr.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
```

this method, however, takes too long. Is there a way to make this loop faster with as small changes as possible?

Thanks

Comment: Use an image-loading library, such as Picasso or Glide, to load the images asynchronously as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the image path into Bitmap object. You can directly pass the path of the Image and on Adapter class set the Image like

```
 Picasso.with(mContext).load(new File(imageUrl)).resize(100,100).into(myViewHolder.imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                      }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });
```